# How do I customize a Map Pin on the Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map in NET Maui?

Tags: maps, maui

I can't find any documentation in NET Maui on how to create a custom map pin. I've found the Xamarin Forms implementation using custom renderers. Is that transferable to NET Maui or am I searching in the work direction?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my opinion, if you do not like it, ignore it completely.

Start by reading this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-7.0

Maui uses Handlers. The situation is quite different in Xamarin. I do not say that you cannot use your Xamarin renderers. You can. But you should be able to customize MAUI controls.

This guy here, has very interesting topics, one of them is regarding pin customization in maui:
https://vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/Customize-map-pins-in-.NET-MAUI/

Also, this guy (works in syncfusion) writes nice blog, about control customization:
https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/how-to-customize-net-maui-controls-with-handler-architecture.aspx

You need to read a lot. And you got to write platform specific code.

I cannot help you more, because I do not use Map control. But I have been getting ideas from those guys, for my own custom control problems. Something may be useful for you too.

Comment: While I would have liked to have more support directly in Maui, using custom handlers worked like a charm! I just didn't find the resource you linked to. Thank you very much!